# Custom ceilometer metrics

Tags: openstack, openstack-horizon, ceilometer

I am trying to add a custom metric to ceilometer via API and have success in adding new metric and new data, but I have fail when try to see this new metric in dashboard.

The comand I gave use:

Get a token:

```
curl -i -X POST http://controller:35357/v2.0/tokens -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "User-Agent: python-keystoneclient" -d '{"auth": {"tenantName": "test", "passwordCredentials": {"username": "admin", "password": "password"}}}'  ;
```

Take token:

```
mysql -e 'use keystone; select id from token;' | tail -n 1
```

Add custom metric with data:

```
curl -X POST -H 'X-Auth-Token: TOKEN' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -d '[{"counter_name": "test","user_id": "admin_user_id","resource_id": "Virtual_machine_ID","resource_metadata": {"display_name": "my_test","my_custom_metadata_1": "value1","my_custom_metadata_2": "value2"},"counter_unit": "%","counter_volume": 10.57762938230384,"project_id": "VM_tenant_ID","counter_type": "gauge"}]'  http://controller:8777/v2/meters/test
```

All of that comands have success =)
Checking with comands like:

> ceilometer sample-list -m test
>
> ceilometer meter-list |grep test
>
> ceilometer statistics -m test

they are returns the data that I have input before. But when I am open dashboard with Resources Usage Overview I can't see new metric in a list.

So I can't found a desicion of my problem. Anybody can help me?

Comment: can you please guide me on how to create a custom meter for applications parameter in ceilometer. Any blogs where you have posted the step by step approach. If you can pass the github link as well, that will be very helpful of you

Comment: check if the ceilometer-api service is running or not?